# How to animate through a plot using Dygraphs i.e "Transitions"

Tags: plot, transition, dygraphs

Say we have a group of data, set up as time(ms) and an associated value.  Now, I would like to slowly plot out the points, so X1, Y1 in the scatter plot would display, then after some delay the next point, etc.  I just need this for a demo.  Down the line, we would like to have a vertical line that would transition through each point in the graph we draw per unit of time.

Here is an example using jqplot:

```
   rendererOptions: {
                // Speed up the animation a little bit.
                // This is a number of milliseconds.  
                // Default for bar series is 3000.  
                animation: {
                    speed: 2500
                },
```

For my purpose for the demo, I would like to just plot out the points again, per time delay.  I could not find anything in the documentation about this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add points to a chart at regular intervals by callin `updateOptions({file: newData})` periodically on your Dygraph object. See http://dygraphs.com/tests/dynamic-update.html for an example of this technique in action.

Comment: I was hoping to see some more involved examples, as what I'm looking to do down the line will be pretty complicated.  Now, you use the window object, so I would assume if we put a graph on a panel div, that panel has a window object associated with it, correct?  Forgive me, I'm a bit of a newbie at this.  If it means anything, your graphs look great as you have some beautification built in.